# st_contour - mapping should be created with aes

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, aesthetics, r-stars

I know the "mapping should be created with aes" bit has been done to death, so I hope this is a sufficiently unusual case, since I've tried to work out why it's happening and come up short.

Per [this thread](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/465), I can plot my `stars` object in `ggplot` & `ggmap` fine as a surface using `geom_stars`. I'm trying to plot that same object as contours. The data file in question is [All_Rasters_Scaled.asc](https://github.com/SimonDedman/dBBMM_HomeRange/blob/main/data/All_Rasters_Scaled.asc).

```
library(stars)
lemons.ras <- read_stars("All_Rasters_Scales.asd")) %>%
  st_set_crs(2958) %>%
  st_transform(4326)
ggplot() +
geom_stars(data = lemons.ras)
```

Works fine. Edzer informed me that `st_contour` returns an `sf` object with the contours, and you have to pass **that** to `geom_sf`. So:

```
mycontour <- st_contour(x = lemons.ras, contour_lines = FALSE, breaks = c(0.5, 0.95))
ggmap(myMap) + geom_sf(mycontour)
```

> Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

I was under the impression that this error shouldn't be seen when using `sf` objects, indeed that this is somewhat the point of the `sf` ecosystem, since the `geometry` column is present. The object might have been incorrectly created somehow and have all NAs though:

```
st_bbox(mycontour)
```

> xmin ymin xmax ymax
>
> NA   NA   NA   NA

But if I create it without any parameters specified:

```
mycontour <- st_contour(x = lemons.ras)
```

The bbox output is the same. Also the contour min/maxes in the object are oddly overlapping. Regardless of the way I create `mycontour`, I get the same `aes` error. Trying to specify aes:

```
geom_sf(mycontour, mapping = aes())
```

> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which
> will replace the existing one. Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object
> 'lon' not found

Or

```
geom_sf(mycontour, mapping = aes(geometry))
```

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x Coordinate system already
> present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing
> one. Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lat' not found

Basically it looks like the `ggmap` / `ggplot` framework doesn't understand that `mycontour`, created by `geom_contour`, is an `sf` object, and that its `aes` mapping is the `geometry` column.

Any suggestions very much appreciated. I'm not sure if there's an underlying issue whereby `geom_contour` is failing to create the object properly and therefore all values are `NA`, and I don't know how to extract the `geometry` data from an `sf` object.

Code for the `mymap` object for `ggmap` is:

```
myLocation <- st_bbox(lemons.ras) %>% as.vector()
myMap <- get_map(location = myLocation)
```

But `sf` objects typically work fine with a blank `ggplot()+`

Thanks in advance!

Edit: adding more details:

```
class(mycontour)
```

> "sf"         "data.frame"

```
mycontour$geometry[1]
```

> Geometry set for 1 feature
>
> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
>
> Dimension: XY
>
> Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
>
> Geodetic CRS: WGS 84
>
> MULTIPOLYGON (((NA NA, NA NA, NA NA, NA NA, NA ...

More edits:

```
ggplot() +
geom_stars(lemons.ras)
```

Works fine, creates:

[image: raster data]

```
st_bbox(lemons.ras)
```

> xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax
>
> -79.28970  25.68331 -79.21143  25.78939

i.e. looks fine also.

```
summary(lemons.ras)
```

> ```
>                    Length Class  Mode
> ```
>
> All_Rasters_Scaled.asc 36270  -none- numeric

Including or not including `x=` in `st_contour()` shouldn't (and, having tested, doesn't) make a difference. I know it's unnecessary but I like doing it for two reasons:

1. It rarely hurts to be explicit, especially when sharing code & teaching others.
2. With RStudio's code completion macros, you can hit tab within a function and it'll give you the list of parameters to choose from. I try to use those in order. Also if you explicitly use `x` (or whatever the default first parameter is) then the macro will stop giving you that parameter option. All minor semantics though :)

`lemons.ras$All_Rasters_Scaled.asc` is a matrix arrray, 155x234 in size, with values ranging from 0 to 1 (it's been scaled, hence the name). So conceptually none of the values in `mycontour` from `st_contour` should be `NA`.

`st_contour`'s param `na.rm` is default `TRUE` thus should be removing these `NA`s in any case, I feel.

I'm increasingly thinking that there's an issue with `st_contour`...

According to `getGDALVersionInfo()` is have "GDAL 3.2.2, released 2021/03/05"

@lovelery 's code to test:

```
tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
x = read_stars(tif)[, 1:50, 1:50, 1:2]
x[[1]] = round(x[[1]]/5)
l = st_contour(x, contour_lines = TRUE, breaks = 11:15)
plot(l[1], key.pos = 1, pal = sf.colors, lwd = 2, key.length = 0.8)
```

Works fine:

[image: example code]

`l` is created with `st_contour(x, contour_lines = TRUE, ...)` which makes a multi linestring feature instead of a multipolygon feature. If I do the same to `lemons.ras`, the resulting `mycontour` has all NA values, which is probably related to the problem. `l`:

[image: l]

`mycontour`:

[image: mycontour]

The files that created them with `st_contour`: `x`:

[image: x]

`lemons.ras` (note there **are** values here, from 0 to 1):

[image: lemons.ras]

Differences:

- `x$L7_ETMs.tif` values are integers. But having upscaled `lemons.ras` values to integers, `mycontour` still fails.
- `x$L7_ETMs.tif` is 3 dimensions [50 x 50 x 2], `lemons.ras$All_Rasters_Scales.asc` is 2 dimensions [155 x 234]. But the code works with `plot(l[1])` and `plot(l)` so the extra band/dimension shouldn't matter, right?!

Edit: if I remove the `1:2` from the `x = read_stars`, `plot(l)` works the same. BUT: x is now Type: list [50 x 50 x 6]. Before was [50 x 50 x 2]. Ok this is because the input file, `L7_ETMs.tif`, is [349 x 352 x 6] and the indexing `read_stars(tif)[, 1:50, 1:50, 1:2]` constrains this to 2 bands.

`st_dimensions(x)` gives:

[image: x dims]

`st_dimensions(lemons.ras)` gives:

[image: lemons.ras dims]

So this might be the root of the issue. Even though lemons.ras `plot`s perfectly fine having been imported as a raster and read into `stars`, it seems to be missing `band` attributes, which honestly don't look to be adding much of anything, but maybe the `st_contour` code expects them to be present and fails without them.

Actually looking at the direct output of st_dimensions is maybe even more illuminating: For x:

[image: x dims more]

For lemons.ras:

[image: lem dims more]

Compared to `x`, `lemons.ras` has `NA` `offset`, `delta` and `point`. `x` has `NULL` `value`s, so I guess the `x/y` geometry data for `x` is within the `band`, whereas for `lemons.ras` it's in the `value`s. LAWD raster data is confusing.

Reading the [stars intro](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars1.html) again, it looks like splitting & merging attributes requires the `band` to be present in the first place. So the problem looks increasingly to be due to the `lemons.ras` input raster not having a `band` dimension.

The file was created with:

```
writeRaster(x, name, format = "ascii", datatype = "FLT4S", bylayer = T)
```

I don't know if the choice of `ascii` means no band info? I doubt it?
After creation of the original raster earlier in the code, it has properties:

> class      : RasterLayer
>
> dimensions : 3270, 3245, 10611150  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>
> resolution : 50, 50  (x, y)
>
> extent     : 594830.7, 757080.7, 2763971, 2927471  (xmin, xmax, ymin,
> ymax)
>
> crs        : +proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
>
> source     : memory
>
> names      : layer
>
> values     : 1, 1  (min, max)

DURING creation of this file, it looks like `band` or `layer` parameters were NOT used. This is necessarily going to be a single layer/band raster, and evidently the output is successful enough that it survives multiple rounds of processing, editing, joining, applying, etc etc, before hitting this issue. Values were added after raster creation with `setValues`. And there is the "names : layer" entry above.

**intermediate Conclusion this morning:**

my input raster doesn't have a band attribute and is just a plain/flat raster, which is fine for simple plotting but evidently isn't the rich format that stars expects. However stars will work with this file and convert it to a (weak) stars object, but then it will fail in st_contour, likely due to the lack of the band.

Comment: Maybe, first action: what exactly does `class(mycontour)` return?

Comment: details added now, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.I'm not sure of my reasoning because I haven't had to use the `st_contour()` function yet. That said, I'll give you my understanding of your problem and hope that it can put you on the right track. The `mycontour` object is indeed of type `sf` but it is completely empty! This would explain why the functions `st_bbox()` or `geom_sf()` do not work. Two hypotheses are possible to explain the fact that `mycontour` is empty: either the `st_contour` function is badly parameterized, or the `stars` object `lemon.ras` has a problem/is corrupted.

Comment: Concerning the first hypothesis, something bothers me in `st_contour()`. Why do you write `x = lemons.ras`. I think `x=` is too much and you should write your line of code like this `mycontour <- st_contour(lemons.ras, contour_lines = FALSE, breaks = c(0.5, 0.95))` Maybe that's where the problem lies.

Regarding the second hypothesis (if the proposed correction for hypothesis 1 does not solve the problem), it would be interesting if you could provide us with what R returns when you display the summary of the `lemon.ras` object

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Edits added at the bottom with all info.

Comment: Thanks for the test and the additional information. Actually, I agree with you more and more that the problem is probably with the `st_contour()` function itself. In any case, I don't see what we are doing wrong.

Maybe two last checks before submitting the problem to Edzer:

1. What version of GDAL is returned when you run the following code `sf_extSoftVersion()`? The version must be >= 2.4.0 for the `st_contour()` function to work correctly.

Comment: 2. Does the following reprex work correctly on your computer? `tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")` 
`x = read_stars(tif)[, 1:50, 1:50, 1:2]` 
`x[[1]] = round(x[[1]]/5)` 
`l = st_contour(x, contour_lines = TRUE, breaks = 11:15)` 
`plot(l[1], key.pos = 1, pal = sf.colors, lwd = 2, key.length = 0.8)` 

If everything is OK on these two points, I suggest you report your problem here: https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues so that Edzer can help you find the solution. For my part, this is way beyond my own skills! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks again. Gdal version added. Plot code works. Adding more info comparing the objects from your code to mine, and trying to work out why they end up different.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete feedback. I think we are making progress... and maybe we are close to the goal :-)

It appears that `.asd` files are not supported by `sf/stars` objects. You can get the list of drivers by running the function  `st_drivers()` as is. So I think you should save your image file `All_Rasters_Scales` in `tif` format and it should work. Anyway, I keep my fingers crossed for you and let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this. [It looks like](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/465) the problem is due to my having transformed the original raster into a curvilinear format, which causes st_contour to fail

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback and the very useful and instructive link! I actually didn't think about this problem... and I should have! So my bad. Anyway, I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.